# send post in wordpress with flutter

Tags: wordpress, flutter

hi i want to send post to wordpress with api in flutter and i use [JSON API](https://github.com/PI-Media/json-api) and [JSON API USER](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/)  Plugin to get api.

when i want to send post with api i got error

```json
{
    "status":"error",
    "error":"You need to login with a user that has 'edit_posts' capacity."
}
```

**this is my code:**

```dart
Future<http.Response> sendTahlil(_title, _content) async {
  final response = await http.get(
    "https://example.com/api/get_nonce/?controller=posts&method=create_post",
  );

  var decodedjson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  // String nonCode = jsonDecode(decodedjson['nonce']);
  var urlcreat =
      "https://example.com/api/posts/create_post/?nonce=${decodedjson['nonce']}&title=${_title}&content=${_content}";
  final ressend = await http.post(
    urlcreat,
  );
  print(ressend.body);
  print("OOOOOKKKKK");
}
```

Comment: you are missing authentication token check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests) for more info

Comment: thanks for help , i do that but dont work and again i receve this error

Comment: please add stacktrace of error

Comment: im new in flutter can you explain more?